# How to conveniently change from Python ubuntu native to Python Anaconda and vice versa?

Tags: python, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04

I have Linux Ubuntu 16.04 with several versions of python installed.

1. Python 2.7 Ubuntu native
2. Python 3.5 Anaconda
3. Python 2.7 Anaconda

The default for my terminal is (2), and I can easily switch to (3) with 'source activate' command. This is because I added the environment for (3) using conda after I have installed (2).

However, since (1) is linked to a PDE solver package ([fenics](https://fenicsproject.org/index.html)) that I want to use from time to time, is there a practical way to set (1) as the default for a while? Is there any quick way to do it for example like when I changed (2) to (3) and vice versa?

Comment: Change your PATH environment variable to point to [1] first. `export PATH=whatever`.

Comment: So if I want to go back to [2] as the default, set the PATH to point to [2] again?

Comment: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/813 this issue has a hacky solution to it.

Comment: Sorry cel, I don't get it. Could you please elucidate the best way according to the thread?

Comment: Offtopic: Please avoid using "[1]" and use "(1)" instead, since any link addition will turn the "[1]" into a link as well. (this message will be deleted)

Comment: I see. OK, Ihave edited the answer too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get what I wanted by adding this line to .bashrc:

```
export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"
```

which give the location of (1). However, do not delete or commented out the path to the anaconda. Hence, I can access (2) by using:

```
source activate root
```

and can easily switch to (3) by:

```
source activate py27
```

Note: py27 is the name I gave to (3) environment when I installed it using conda.

Then, if I want to go back to (1), just use:

```
source deactivate
```

Answer (score 0):

I added these lines to my .bashrc:

```
#### # Alias to activate different Python-conda environments:
alias py27="source activate py27"
alias py36="source activate py36"
alias py27off="source deactivate py27"
alias py36off="source deactivate py36"
#### # added by Anaconda3 4.4.0 installer
export PATH="/home/adcp/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
#### # Choose python 2.7 native as default
export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"
```

So 1. is native and to switch from this to #2 - conda 2.7 (3.6)- just type py27 (py36). To switch back to native python just type py27off (py36off) and `which python` should return `/usr/bin/python` instead of `/home/user/anaconda3/envs/py27/bin/python` or `/home/user/anaconda3/envs/py36/bin/python`